# Normal user can delete important files

Tags: permissions, filesystems

I am concerned about the possibility that a normal user can delete important files from like `/etc/passwd` or files from `/boot`. They can do it because the permissions on `/etc` and `/boot` are `drwxr-xr-x`.
Should I worry about this or am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: Have youtried, as a normal user, to delete `/etc/passwd` ? Just 1) make a backup as root, 2) start two session 3) delete **as a normal user** the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.** The permissions that you see can be split into four components: type of entry, owner permissions, group permissions, and "all" permissions; "all" simply refers to anyone who is neither the owner or a member of the group. What the permissions mean depend on whether the entry is a file or a directory. A more thorough description of how permissions work [is here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes).

So, for this example:

```
$ ls -dl /etc /etc/passwd /etc/shadow
drwxr-xr-x 58 root root 4096 Feb 13 19:08 /etc
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1887 Oct 11 21:49 /etc/passwd
-rw-r-----  1 root root 970 Oct 11 21:49 /etc/shadow
```

For `/etc`:

- `d`: the entry is a directory.
- `rwx`: the owner of the directory (`root`) has full permissions to view and modify (add/delete/rename) file entries, and change to ("`cd`") this directory.
- `r-x`: members of the group (also called `root`, but is not the same as the user called `root`) have permissions to view file entries and change to ("`cd`") this directory.
- `r-x`: everyone else has permissions to view file entries and change to ("`cd`") this directory.

Note that having permission to read a directory does not mean that you can read the contents of individual files: that is what file permissions are for.

Individual files work in a similar way, but the permissions refer to reading, writing and executing the file itself.

For `/etc/passwd`:

- `-`: the entry is a regular file.
- `rw-`: the owner (`root`) can read and write to this file, but not run it directly from the command line.
- `r--`: members of the group (`root`) can only read this file.
- `r--`: everyone else can read this file.

Originally the `/etc/passwd` file did have (encrypted) passwords in it, but that was judged to be a security risk so the passwords were moved to a "shadow" copy of the password file called `/etc/shadow`. It is only accessible by the `root` user and group (`-rw-r-----`): regular users cannot view it.

Comment: +1, but it took me a little while to realise that "...and change to this directory" meant "`cd` **to** it" rather than an unusual way of saying "... and change the directory". When it clicked, it was obvious. before then, not so much.  overall, a great explanation.

Comment: I'm glad that this was helpful. There are other letters that you may see in the permissions fields, like `s` for setgid/setuid and `t` for sticky files, but they're fairly uncommon and generally don't get touched unless you have specific requirements (you'll know if you need to set them!)

Comment: One last point of information: symbolic links will always have the form `lrwxrwxrwx`: this is not a security issue because the permissions only refer to the link itself (the system looks at the actual file for the real permissions.)

Comment: I'm not the OP (nor am i a newcomer to unix permissions).  I was just commenting that you did a good job of explaining how perms work.   BTW, I almost commented "I think you mean **can't** change the directory" until I realised you meant `cd`.   Even now, I think there's probably a better way of phrasing that (disclaimer: I have had a flu-like virus for several weeks now and it is making my brain slow and dopey)

Comment: I've added a bit to hopefully clarify what "change to" means.

Comment: that's perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

To delete a file a user needs write permission on the parent directory of the file. With the permissions set to `drwxr-xr-x` only the owner of those directorys can delete files in them

Answer (score 1):

The owner of **/etc** and **/boot** is or should be **root**.

```
echo test > /etc/test 
bash: /etc/test: Permission denied
```

Only the owner *root* has the permission to create files or delete them from the directory.